# Hide Dojo Enhanced grid header name

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I have a requirement where I need to hide the DOJO Enhanced grid column name

```
Ex: look into the jsfiddle link 

http://jsfiddle.net/9dD3C/
```

Here Column1 Column2 column3 column4 are displayed. My requirement is to hide "Column1" value and make it as blank and retain everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/*set up layout*/

```
var layout = [
  { 'name': 'Column 1','field': 'id', 'width': '100px'},
  {'name': 'Column 2', 'field': 'col2', 'width': '100px'},
  {'name': 'Column 3', 'field': 'col3', 'width': '200px'},
  {'name': 'Column 4', 'field': 'col4', 'width': '150px'}
];
for(var i=0; i<layout.length; i++){
         layout[i].name=[];

}
```

Comment: Please explain how this helps

Comment: @user7141263 wow! thanks for the help it worked. For the given jsfiddle, I slightly tweaked your code                                               for(var i=0; i<layout.length; i++){

for(var k=0; k<layout[i].length; k++){

if(layout[i][k].name=="Column 1"){
layout[i][k].name=[];
}
}
        

}

Comment: @02genum I want to display an image based on the mimetype for each row. EX: if mimetype="image/tiff" I will display tiff image for that column. But I don't want to display the column header name for it. Hope this helps.